# Return distinct Criteria result as String in Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, criteria

I am trying to Create a criteria that will select distinct values from a column. How can I return this value as String;

I have this:

```
Criteria criteria = 
    session.createCriteria(Students.class)
           .add(Restrictions.eq("studentYear","2"))
           .add(Restrictions.eq("studentSemester","1"))
           .setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("studentHostel")));
```

any ideas will be appreciated. Can I convert this to a String value?

Comment: Like, comma-separated? Can't you just do a String.join on the result set?

Comment: @Stanley This will return List<Object> only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to do it manually like below.

```
Criteria criteria = 
    session.createCriteria(Students.class)
           .add(Restrictions.eq("studentYear","2"))
           .add(Restrictions.eq("studentSemester","1"))
           .setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("studentHostel")));

List<String> listObj = criteria.list();
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
for(String str: listObj){
 sb.append(str+',');
}
```